# Site Signup Issues

Tags: bug, login

Not sure if this is a new issue or not but I have noticed recently that when I am signing up on a new Stack Exchange Site it appears that it logs me in. However when I go to take an action on that site such as cast a vote on a question/answer or leave a comment it informs me that I must login to the site in order to perform that action.

After I sign up on the site it does appear as if I am logged in as it shows my avatar and reputation along with inbox and reputation notifications in the top bar. However when I refresh the page it resets to a not logged in state and I have to log in to do anything and afterwards the site functions as expected.

Is the way this is behaving a bug or am I not understanding how the signup process should work? This happened to me last night on a site and today on another site.

Comment: That sure sounds like a bug. Which sites are you experiencing this on and what browser are you using?

Comment: @Adam it has already been reported, and happened to me too.  (for me it was on http://diy.stackexchange.com/, went in there to suggest an edit after Smoky detected something)

Comment: @AdamLear I was using the latest stable version of chrome on Windows 10 last night and on ubuntu toady. Last night was on RPG stack exchange and today was on unix and linux

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thank you for pointing out the duplicate question for me it seems I did not search hard enough to find it.